# Two dimensional brownian motion first passage time

Tags: random-walks, reference-request, stochastic-processes

Hello,

I am looking for information on how to solve/compute first passage time for  two dimensional Brownian motion.

any papers, references, books or web links for study will be helpful.
thanks
lakshmi

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-hitting-time_model

I've always just run the sample path (so, a loop which cumulatively sums $dX(t)$) until some condition is met, then end the loop, returing $t$ and $X(t)$. I guess your condition would be $X(t) \in E$, for some borel set $E$.

-nick

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this page on the Azimuth wiki: [First hitting time problem](http://www.azimuthproject.org/azimuth/show/First-hitting-time+problem), there are references and more references on the linked pages.

The solution of the one-dimensional diffusion process that is absorbed at two boundary points, which is explained on that page, can be generalized to more dimensions...